# How to use a second GPU on a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 ? [Nvidia Optimus]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.04.2.
I have two GPU on my laptop : Intel HD graphics 5500 and Nvidia Geforce 950M
I would like to use the GPU from Nvidia.

I've been tinkering with the drivers for the Geforce 950M and I currently have theses ones installed:
[image: Drivers installed]

I've tried using Prime and Bumblebee but I either didn't understand how to use them or they didn't seem to work.

I'm pretty clueless on what my next step should be.

Tldr:

1. How do I activate my second GPU ?
2. Which driver should I use ?

Edit : Solved ! Disabled secure boot.

Comment: You should be able to use the `prime-select` command
`sudo prime-select nvidia` and `sudo prime-select intel` to revert.
FYI you will need to reboot to activate it

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Do you have any details of what happens when you do that?

Comment: @fmo it says `Info: the nvidia profile is already set`

I've tried `nvidia-sim` and it displays `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

Comment: Problem solved : Disabled secure boot